# How to remove certain values in list but that value occurs more than one?

Tags: android, list, kotlin, removeall

Let's say I have

```
val asd = mutableListOf("lulu","bubu","gugu","bubu")
```

If I use `asd.remove("bubu")`, it only removes the first bubu.

How to remove all bubu in asd without a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use removeAll function that takes Collection as input which is array-List of string in this case. It will remove all occurences of all elements present in the parameter.

```
asd.removeAll(mutableListOf("bubu"))
```

Use this code and it should work now.

Answer (score 3):

Even a single `remove()` call is using a loop (under the hood). To remove all occurrences using a single loop under the hood, you can use `removeAll { it == "bubu" }`.